# Twitter UserTimeline and TweetTimelineListAdapter not scrollable on Android

Tags: android, twitter

I'm using the TwitterKit and UserTimeline and TweetTimelineListAdapter to list tweets from a specific user (in this case, realdonaldtrump):

```
final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)LinearLayout.inflate(context, R.layout.node_social_twitter, null);

final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder().screenName("realdonaldtrump").build();
final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(context).setTimeline(userTimeline).build();
final ListView tweetsListview = (ListView)vg.getChildAt(0);
tweetsListview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:background="#f9f"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/node_default_spacing_half"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm able to see just one tweet.

If I make the listview a fixed height (say, 400dp), I'm able to see more tweets, although many times a tweet is only half visible and I'm again unable to scroll.

Any tips on how to fix this? An ideal scenario would be to indicate how many tweets I'd like to show, and make it scrollable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Hi @Mindshifter! No, same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Adding items manually (without the adapter) seemed to work, at least to be able to get N amount of tweets and have them all fit completely. In this solution tweetsViewGroup is a Linear Layout.

```
final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder().screenName(twitterHandle).build();
userTimeline.previous(null, new Callback<TimelineResult<Tweet>>() {
    @Override
    public void success(final Result<TimelineResult<Tweet>> result) {
        // For now we'll just display 3 items
        // TODO Ensure we have 3 or more tweets
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            final Tweet tweet = result.data.items.get(x);
            tweetsViewGroup.addView(new TweetView(context, tweet));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(final TwitterException ignored) {
        vg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```